# ParseException EOF error in hive

Tags: hive, parseexception

I have a simple query but it fails with the ParseException

```
select * from apachelog
where split(regexp_extract(cookie, 'PHPSESSID.*?\;', 0), '=')[1]='7nsi2pj4icv875sdfdcoj90bv6;'
and day='2015-10-01' limit 10;

FAILED: ParseException line 2:91 character '<EOF>' not supported here
```

Where did I make some stupid error?